# What causes a php foreach loop to terminate?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, terminate

I have been having problems on one of my foreach loops where PART of the loop terminates after just one iteration, with no output or error.

After searching the web for answers, I still don't know any possible causes for this issue (and the code is too large to be useful to the community...)

Therefore my question is, "what are the possible causes for a foreach loop to terminate after just one iteration?" (assuming more iterations are required)

Comment: maybe a `break` instruction.

Comment: `break`, `die` and `return` can all cancel a foreach totally, `continue` can skip the iteration but will not break a loop.

Comment: `"PART of the loop terminates after just one iteration"` = One item in the array.

Comment: @vascowhite `(assuming more iterations are required)`

Comment: @Sammaye That assumption may be wrong, many are.

Comment: @user1973200 what was the problem you were facing? i'm facing a similar kinda issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to stop a foreach loop. Here are a few examples:

```
<?php
$range = range(1,10);

// continue;
foreach($range as $r){
    if($r!=1){
        continue;
    }
    echo $r.'<br>';
}

// break;
foreach($range as $r){
    if($r>1){
        break;
    }
    echo $r.'<br>';
}

// die;
foreach($range as $r){
    if($r>1){
        die;
    }
}
```

Note: `continue` will not break out of the foreach loop, but can cause data rows to be "skipped"

Comment: `continue` won't terminate the loop, but skip to the next index.

Comment: yeah, i added that to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

I think that you should have to follow this link http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for better knowledge about foreach loop.

Comment: If he were experiencing this then the foreach would throw a fatal and would not even go into the first iteration.